# Django form validation for checking uniqueness of record before submitting

Tags: django, postgresql, validation

I have database table columns like:

| FPB_Code | Transaction_Date | Ministry_Code | Created_Date | Created_By | Modified_Date | Modified_By |

I have created a form using **Django and before submitting the form, I want to check whether records matching from**

(|FPB_Code | Transaction_Date | Ministry_Code| ) exists or not?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use Django with PostgreSQL.In the Django Model you can make sure that a field is unique.

Just put **unique=True** in the field

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use filter method which returns a new QuerySet containing objects that match the given lookup parameters.
you can then use exists function as its useful for searches relating to both object membership in a QuerySet and to the existence of any objects in a QuerySet, particularly in the context of a large QuerySet.

Please note this does not check for uniqueness it checks if something already exists in a database.

To ensure that only unique objects are created in the database, provide the parameter `unique=True`  on all the fields you want to remain unique.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/